# In topological space $(X, \mathcal{O})$ with $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq X$ do we have $X\setminus\partial A=X^\circ$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I got that result by basic set operations and that $X \setminus \bar{A} = (X \setminus A)^\circ$ but am not sure if it is correct.

$
X \setminus \partial A\\
= X \setminus (\bar{A} \setminus A^\circ)\\
= (X \cap A^\circ) \cup (X \setminus \bar{A})\\
= (X \cup (X \setminus \bar{A})) \cap (A^\circ \cup (X \setminus \bar{A}))\\
= X \cap(A \cup (X \setminus A))^\circ \\
= X \cap X^\circ = X^\circ
$

$\partial A$ denotes the boundary, $\bar{A}$ the closure and $A^\circ$ the kernel (all interior points) of A.

Comment: What if you take $A=\varnothing$?

Comment: @drhab just out of curiosity where would that be a problem?

Comment: @bodokaiser Go through your proof line by line taking $A=\emptyset$ (so $\overline A= A^\circ=\emptyset$).  At one point, you will find that the equality does not hold any more.  That is where your problem is.

Comment: The result is certainly not true in general.  For example, take $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=[0,1]$.  Then $X\setminus\partial A=\mathbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$.  You should also bear in mind that if $X$ is a topological space, then $X^\circ=X$ (considering $X$ as a subset of itself).

Comment: @Donkey_2009 +1 you beat me on time.

Comment: In order to find out what is wrong in the proof just go along the lines with the example of @Donkey_2009 (or with $A=\varnothing$). Then you will meat the equality that is wrong automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is not true.  Take the circle $\mathbb{S}^1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.  We have in this case the interior of the circle is empty, and in particular $\partial \mathbb{S}^1 = \mathbb{S}^1$.  Clearly $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{S}^1$ is not the full interior of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is open in itself).